# Sleep and restart issue related to registry or BIOS

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-registry, kernel, asus-laptop

I have been looking all over the internet for about half a year now..

Before:
1. Installed many antivirus programs
2. sucked (AVG) so I uninstalled it
3. AVG gave me MacAfee AntiVirus while uninstalling
4. Uninstalled MacAfee
5. Whole computer broke down, internet and computer was inoperable.
6. Restarted internet and reset computer.
7. Computer fixed, but without product key (Accidentally switched to Windows 8.1 Pro)
8. Sleep not working
9. Restart hangs a few seconds on black screen after kernel exit then computer shuts off, never comes back on again after restart.

Now:
Switched back to Windows 8.1, with valid product key. 
Running computer completely fine on everything but sleep and restart

ALERT: My computer was completely fine until I uninstalled MacAfee, then now my computer just wont sleep or restart properly.

I have already turned off fast reboot, and turned off portable operating system.
I have already reset my computer.

Specs:
Intel i3-2 Processor
8GB DD43 RAM
ASUS X550CA (2-3 Years old)

EDIT: In case you didn't catch on to the issue.. The restart works up to the computer itself restarting, it hangs for about 5-10 seconds on a black screen then computer shuts off.. The computer never comes back on after restart.

EDIT: Shutdown works all the way up to **right before** kernel shutdown, it infinitely hangs until I force shutdown the PC.

EDIT: The issue relates to the registry or BIOS, because I already had done a clean installation of my PC.

EDIT: This is low priority, but it would help a ton if someone knew the answer to this..

Comment: "The issue relates to the registry or BIOS": it can't be the registry if you did a clean install.

Comment: "My computer was completely fine until I uninstalled MacAfee" Not relevant if you did a clean install.

Comment: If you have really done a clean install please remove everything from your question that happened before the clean install as it is not relevant (but is confusing).

Comment: +DavidPostill First of all the registry does not get cleaned after a computer reset, also you completely misread my whole question. And the things before the incident is relevant because it can help get more information on what is happening. Someone at your level should know this stuff, now someone smart come and help me here please.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand what a "reset" is: Reset PC: This feature is similar to "Reset to Default" or "Restore Factory Settings" feature found in mobiles and tablets. **This feature removes everything from your PC and reinstalls Windows from scratch.**

Comment: If you believe you registry is still intact then you did not do a "reset". Please get your terminology correct (someone at my level does know this stuff) ;)

Comment: +DavidPostill I did a computer reset and it doesn't clear registry, but aside of that I need help with the sleep and restart issue can someone help?

Comment: <shrug> Good luck solving your problem ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah.. I believed that the registry would clear if you did a clean install, and it does. I was believing my pap on that reply lol.